# Get AD Group Members from AD using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to find AD group members from given groups in csv file as input. the groups contains Users and Groups also. below is sample input data

[image]

I wrote the below code. for users I am getting the output (i.e. for the first entry), but for the second one, as they are groups within group, I am not able to fetch the email.

```
$GroupCollection= Import-csv -Path "C:\Groups.csv"


$Report = @()
Foreach($Group in $GroupCollection){
$MemberGroup=@()
$Group = $Group.'OPE DLs'

if($Group -match '@')
{
$pos = $Group.IndexOf("@")
$leftPart = $Group.Substring(0, $pos)
}
else
{
$leftPart = $Group
}
$MemberGroup =   Get-ADGroupMember -identity $leftPart -recursive | Get-ADUser -Properties mail | Select-Object mail 
$MemberGroups = ($MemberGroup.mail) -join "`r`n"
if($MemberGroups -ne ""){
$Out = New-Object PSObject
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name 'Contract Details' -Value $Group.'Customer subset'
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name 'Group Name' -Value $leftPart
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name 'Member Groups' -Value $MemberGroups

    $Report += $Out
}
}
$Report | Sort-Object Name | FT -AutoSize
$Report | Sort-Object Name | Export-Csv -Path ‘C:\Group-MemberGroups-Report.csv’ -NoTypeInformation
```

Please let me know how to get the details. Is the approach is fine or there is any other way to do this.

expected output

[image]

Comment: You need to test inside a loop to see what kind of objects `Get-ADGroupMember` returned. If `objectClass -eq 'user'` then do `Get-ADUser`, elseif `objectClass -eq 'group'` then use `Get-ADGroup`. if  `objectClass -eq 'computer'` then don't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, if the object returned by `Get-ADGroupMember` is a group, you won't get results by piping it through to `Get-ADUser`, because... it is a group, not a user.

You need to loop over the results and depending on what type the object is (group, user or computer) you use either `Get-ADUser` or `Get-ADGroup` (not interested in computer objects).

Try

```
$Report = foreach ($Group in $GroupCollection){
    $groupName = ($Group.'OPE DLs' -split '@')[0]
    $groupMembers =  Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $groupName -Recursive | ForEach-Object {
        $adObject = $_
        switch ($adObject.objectClass) {
            'group' { ($adObject | Get-ADGroup -Properties mail).mail }
            'user'  { ($adObject | Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress).EmailAddress }
        }

    }
    if (@($groupMembers).Count) {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            'Group Name'       = $groupName
            'Contract Details' = $Group.'Customer subset'
            'Member Groups'    = $groupMembers -join [environment]::NewLine
        }
    }
}
$Report = $Report | Sort-Object 'Group Name'

$Report | Format-Table -AutoSize
$Report | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Group-MemberGroups-Report.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Notes:

- adding to an array with `+=` is extremely wasteful because the **entire** array needs to be rebuilt in memory on each iteration
- To take the group name as the part left of the `@` character, I simply use the `-split` operator and take the first element (`[0]`)
- To output an object, I'm using a `[PsCustomObject]@{..}` construct rather than the old (pre PowerShell 3.0) `New-Object PSObject` method